# Laravel 5.6 download file ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, download

I have a REST API in Laravel 5.6

The users can upload theirs file in a non-public folder.

My problem is that now I want to let the user download the file only if the JWT token is valid and if the user has the right privilege.

My actual code is the following:

jquery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
});

$.get('/api//download?' + $.param({
     file: encodeURIComponent(fileNonPublicPath) //e.g. company_id/file.pdf
}))
.done((data) => {
     console.log('file content', data);
})
.fail((err) => {
      console.error(err);
});
```

Laravel Controller:

```
$file = urldecode($request->input('file'));
$user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->token);
if(checkUserRole($user,$file){
   $pathToFile = Storage::disk('documents')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($file);
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $pathToFile);
   finfo_close($finfo);
   $headers = array('Content-Type' => $mime,);
   return response()->download($pathToFile, 'originalfilename', $headers);
}
return response()->json([], 403); //forbidden
```

This code is working fine except that the browser receive the content of the file in ajax and then the user cannot download it.

What is the solution not compromising the security of the stored files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stream the download if it isn't a file.
`response->streamDownload()`

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads):

> Sometimes you may wish to turn the string response of a given operation into a downloadable response without having to write the contents of the operation to disk. You may use the streamDownload method in this scenario. This method accepts a callback, file name, and an optional array of headers as its arguments:

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
echo GitHub::api('repo')
            ->contents()
            ->readme('laravel', 'laravel')['contents'];
}, 'laravel-readme.md');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide an example with my code? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following solution:

in the javascript file:

```
// onclick callback:
window.location = '/download?' + $.param({
   token: encodeURIComponent(STRING_TOKEN),
   file: encodeURIComponent(file)
});
```

Create a new non-guarded route in web.php

```
Route::get('/download', 'UploadController@download');
```

In the UploadController:

```
$file = urldecode($request->input('file'));
$token = urldecode($request->input('token'));

//This doesn't work
// $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);

// Then I used the same lib that JWTAuth uses to encode/decode the token
$secret = config('jwt.secret');
$jws = SimpleJWS::load($token);
if (!$jws->isValid($secret)) {
    return response()->json([], 401); // unauthorized
} 
$payload = $jws->getPayload();
$userId = User::find($payload["user"]["id"]);

$user = App\User::find($userId);
if(checkUserRole($user,$file){ 
   $pathToFile = Storage::disk('documents')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($file);
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $pathToFile);
   finfo_close($finfo);
   $headers = array('Content-Type' => $mime,);
   return response()->download($pathToFile, 'originalfilename', $headers);
 }
 return response()->json([], 403); //forbidden
```

This should be secure enough.